# What are Metalbeard's "Rules of the Sea"?

Tags: the-lego-movie

In the *The Lego Movie* rule 1 of the sea is "Never sit on a pirates face".

> For reference, this is covered when they are breaking into the Octon tower, and Metalbeard disguises himself as a photocopier. Just after this one of the robots photocopies its butt, which enrages the metal-pirate.

Just after the above, Metalbeard states the rule, and the scene cuts back to his ship, where there were a bunch of other rules of the sea.

**Is there a complete list of "Metalbeard's Rules of the Sea"?**

Comment: This seems like it would be a better fit over on the Movies and TV stack.  It doesn't really deal with either the sci-fi or fantasy elements of the movie.

Comment: @Monty129 - It's got Batman, Superman, Star Wars and Green Lantern and you think it's not suited for here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Official Lego Movie [Metalbeard's Metal Beard's Rules of the Sea Facebook Page](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.562937050471392.1073741835.142731419158626&type=1) has a complete list.

Two are seen in the movie, the others were presumably invented to describe his actions or just for general amusement value;

[image: Metalbeard Rule 1]

and

[image: Metalbeard Rule 2]
[image: Metalbeard Rule 3]
[image: Metalbeard Rule 4]
[image: Metalbeard Rule 5]
[image: Metalbeard Rule 6]